# url rewrite using .httaccess i tried couple of time but failed

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, cpanel

url rewrite using .httaccess i tried couple of time but failed

i am trying to show my url like this

```
https://codingeek.net/preview/html/banting-university
```

insted of this

```
https://codingeek.net/preview/index.php?tslug=banting-university&cat=html
```

i tried using this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule  ^preview/(.+)$  /preview/index.php?tslug=$1&cat=$2   [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace in htaccess

```
RewriteRule  ^preview/(.+)$  /preview/index.php?tslug=$1&cat=$2   [QSA,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule  ^preview/(.+)/(.+)$  /preview/index.php?tslug=$2&cat=$1   [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Do Your website have preview folder and index.php in this folder? .htaccess file in root folder? I tried in local, it run ok. Do you get value of param with $_GET['xxx']?

Comment: yes i have preview folder and index.php inside this folder. also .htaccess file inside this folder.
i get the value using $_GET['xxx']. and yes i get value

Comment: If you have index.php and htaccess in preview folder. You should write htaccess with : <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule  ^(.+)/(.+)$  index.php?tslug=$2&cat=$1   [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: i already did it but not work.
i use this inside the preview folder but still it not works.

Comment: Please provide detail structural of your website. Do you use .htaccess in root folder?  maybe this URl were reˈwritten  to other file.

Comment: i tried it in my localhost still it not work
you can check http://prntscr.com/p8zc5h

htaccess code http://prntscr.com/p8zc7o